# MYSQL order by date format "06:21, 28 February 2014"

Tags: mysql, date, sql-order-by

How can I order in MySQL a column with date values like this "06:21, 28 February 2014"?

Comment: This is why you should store your dates as *dates* and not *strings*

Comment: not my work, I have to deal with this like it is :(

Comment: Doesn't it suck to inherit stuff like this. It could be worse, though....

Comment: now image a whole cms with this quality of work :P that is my pain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it into a date first and then sort by it:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datecol, "%H:%i, %d %M %Y") AS newdate
-- ...
ORDER BY newdate DESC
```

Comment: +1 but with the caveat that this cannot be indexed, so it can only do a filesort. I agree that using a proper DATE data type is recommended, but I understand that it's a legacy problem. People who store dates as strings should be hunted down and forced to sort the data by hand. ;-)